# Splitting strings and appending to new list

Tags: python

I am trying to append a data in to names_list i get it that names_list = list but i don't know why names_list[i] become a string and how do i convert it back to list?

```
for data in f:
    drawingdata = data.split()
    names = drawingdata[0]
    heights = drawingdata[1]
    names_list = names.strip('][').split(',')
    for i in range(len(new_name)):
        names_list[i].append(new_name[i])
```

Comment: welcome to SO :) Please consider giving your question a better title. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know why names_list[i] become a string and how do i convert it back to list?

`names_list` is a list

`names_list[i]` is i_th element of the list (0-indexed), that's why it's a string

What you want to do is `names_list.append`, NOT `names_list[i].append` (you want to append to the whole list, not to an element of the list)

Also, if `new_name` is a single name, then the whole loop is unnecessary because you will append each letter of the name as a separate entry!

Just do `names_list.append(new_name)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i want to append the data to the bottom of the list. you see the names_list is a vertical list without commas and the value of the names within it is only 1 example: ['Tom'] below it ['Sharon'] then the new data is supposed to be appended below it eg: but i dont know how['john']

Comment: Printing is a different from list. List is a data structure. How list displays when you e.g. `print(["a","b"]`is how the whole class converts to string (with `[` and `]`, and commas. What you want to do is print the list elements (not the list as a whole) each in a new line. Or convert the list to a string with newlines in between: `"\n".join(names_list)` - this will make what you want, you just need to print it (*after* what I told you about appending).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the reason:

`names_list[i]` returns a string because `drawingdata` is a list with each value a string, and `names` is the first item in `drawingdata` so it is a string. Therefore `names_list` is splitting `names` into an list with strings, so `names_list[i]` is a string.

To answer your question about converting `name_list[i]` into a list, you can try `[names_list[i]]`, which will give you a list with only `names_list[i]` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the names_list is a vertical list with no comma and the value of the names within it is only 1 example: ['Tom'] below it ['Sharon'] in a vertial form and no commas. i did try your suggestion but the data isnt appended to the bottom of the list then the new data is supposed to be appended below. example of expected output: ['Tom'] below it ['Sharon'] below it ['John']

Comment: @MelvinChing So you want to print the 'names' of each person on a different line?